# Start counting numbers when scroll on specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make working function, which should animate numbers from zero to specific number. And that script should execute when I scroll to its parent div.
But when I scroll there, nothing happens, it stays on zero.

I've downloaded some `jquery.animateNumber.js` which works in its demo, but doesn't work for me. My function is below, thanks for every advice!

```
$(function() {
    var oTop = $('#nase-prace').offset().top - window.innerHeight;
    $(window).scroll(function(){

        var pTop = $('body').scrollTop();
        console.log( pTop + ' - ' + oTop );   //just for your debugging
        if( pTop > oTop ){
            start_count();
        }
    });
});

function start_count(){  
    $('#projektu').animateNumber({ number: 21 });
    $('#klientu').animateNumber({ number: 18 });
    $('#souboru').animateNumber({ number: 78941 });
}
```

Comment: please provide a snippet or a jsfiddle

Comment: @squaleLis https://jsfiddle.net/qu837eah/

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qu837eah/1/).

I added an 'offset-div' in order to make the window scrollable. Moreover I switched off the listener on the `scroll` event when the animation starts.

It seems to work, can you see any other differences with your current code?